# align two buttons horizontally bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to align my two bootstrap buttons side by side (horizontally) and center them inside a table cell but i can't

I use bootstrap4

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom categorie </th>
        <th>Operations</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let categorie of categories">
        <td>{{ categorie.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ categorie.nom }}</td>
        <td >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;align-content: space-between">
              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary">Mettre à jour </button>
              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary">Supprimer</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: add justify-content-center class to the wrapper around the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

Give this style to button div

```
justify-content: center;align-items: center;
```

And add small margin-right (`mr-2`)to first button for a gap between buttons.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom categorie </th>
        <th>Operations</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let categorie of categories">
        <td>{{ categorie.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ categorie.nom }}</td>
        <td >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;justify-content: center;align-items:center;">
              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">Mettre à jour </button>
              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary">Supprimer</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
.xbutton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#xrow{
  text-align: center;
}

.xbutton-row {
   flex: 1;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<td id="xrow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;align-content: space-between">
      <div class="xbutton-row">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary xbutton">Mettre à jour </button>
      </div>
      <div class="xbutton-row">
      <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary xbutton">Supprimer</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Hello @Bodda, i try thid but i have margin but the two buttons aren't center in the cell of the table

Comment: I have edited the comment it should be centerd in the row now

Comment: Hi @Bodda, I completed with the xrow but it doesn't center

Comment: Yes I got it, add to the xbutton style this flex:1; . I will edit the code also

Comment: Hi @Bodda, now it centered but i have two big buttons center on my table cell. I remove the width property in my xbutton class but the result is not sufficient, have you another idea

Comment: Yes because you gave the flex property to the button iself , so you have to cover each button with a div and give that div that flex property after removing it from the xbutton style ... I will edit the code also